# Route to maximize number of visited partitions in a weighted graph for given distance

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms, nonlinear-optimization

How can I find a route through a partitioned weighted graph that visits as many of the partitions as possible, for a given maximum distance? Start and end anywhere.

A real-world example could be to find a route that visits as many European countries as possible in $2000$ miles.

EDIT: by partitioned graph here, I mean that each vertex belongs to exactly one set, and for any $2$ vertices in the same set there exists a path that connects them whose vertices all belong to that set.
The partition is already provided in the problem.
The edge weights could correspond to distances - a max distance constraint is given in the problem.
Again, think about cities belonging to countries, connected by roads.

The solution should be efficient but not necessarily exact. A typical number of partitions would be $\sim 50$. The number of vertices could be in the order of millions.

The image below shows an example for a max distance of $10$ - the path in red visits $3$ partitions.
Example solution

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I suggest explaining what solution approaches you have tried/thought of so far, and giving an example so it's easier to visualise

Comment: Please [edit] your post to define what you mean by a "partitioned weighted graph" and by "partitions".  Are you assuming there is a partition of the vertices of the graph?  Are there any properties of the partition that we can assume, for instance, that each partition is an induced subgraph or a connected subgraph?  What is your question?  Are you looking for any method without regard to efficiency/running time, or are you looking for an efficient method?  About how many partitions do you have, for typical problem instances?

Answer (score 1):

This is called the *set orienteering problem*.  See, for example: https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0377221717310202